# Filling a ternary plot

Tags: python, fill, ternary

I'm using a ternary plot in python to represent some data and I need to fill some regions of it. A simplified example of what I can have is this:

```
import ternary

fig, tax = ternary.figure(scale=1.0)
fig.set_size_inches(10, 10)

x = []
for i in range(100):
  x.append( [0.5, 0.5 - 0.5/(i+1), 0.5/(i+1)] )
tax.plot(x, linewidth=2.0)

tax.get_axes().axis('off')
tax.clear_matplotlib_ticks()
tax.ticks(axis='lbr', linewidth=1, multiple=0.1, tick_formats="%.1f")
tax.boundary()
tax.gridlines(multiple=0.2, color="black")
tax.show()
```

[Ternary example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT7fn.png)

So what I need is to fill the region between the curve and the axes (the right hand side, for instance). I was thinking that maybe adding an extra point to the x data placed in the right vertex would allow me to fill the region inside x. However, I've tried several possible ways of doing this but I don't find the correct function.

Is it even possible to fill a region in a ternary plot?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: What version of ternary are you using? I get AttributeError: module 'ternary' has no attribute 'figure'

Comment: I'm using version 1.0.8